# How to separated a huge table and run a loop to select rows and import to a new table?

Tags: mysql

I have a huge table that contains 24 millions rows of data. I want to run a query that select some of the data and store in a new table.

How to write a loop that do such things?

select first 250,000(250k) rows
run the query
insert data
select another following up 250k rows
run the query
insert data.

Comment: Why do you need a loop? Just use `INSERT INTO new_table (col1, col2, col3, ...) SELECT x, y, z, ... FROM huge_table WHERE ...`?

Comment: because I need to select each of the batch and run some query on it, so i cant do it with the whole huge table, i have to separate the huge table in some batches and run it separately. do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE WhileLoopProc()
    BEGIN
           DECLARE x  INT;
            SET X=0;
           WHILE(x<=24 MILLION) DO
           PREPARE stmt FROM "select u.user_id, u.firstname, u.lastname from  users u limit 250k     offset ?"; 
           EXECUTE stmt USING X; 
           set x=x+250k; 
           END WHILE;
   END
```

Comment: what about the next 250K? and the third 250k until it hits the final batch? will it work for it?

Comment: I don't think you can use a placeholder in the `LIMIT` clause.

Comment: i dont think this will select the next 250k right? it will select 500k instead. is that right?

Comment: let me try this if it works.  Thank you very much!

Comment: and other question is, if the table contains 600k records, it will select 250k, another 250k which is totally 500k, but it will not select the remaining 100k right?